# In the rails 4 console, how do I log all sql activity to file BUT not to the console output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, logging, rails-console

Lots of similar questions ask how to hide sql logs in the console window, and the answers suggest changing the log level of Active Record or turning off AR logging altogether.

However I still want AR to log everything, I just wanted to log it to file only, and not to the console output window (as it makes the console to noisy so I can't see my manual logs).

How do I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [ActiveRecord::Railtie](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb) code is what says to broadcast logger messages to the console:

```
# When loading console, force ActiveRecord::Base to be loaded
# to avoid cross references when loading a constant for the
# first time. Also, make it output to STDERR.
console do |app|
  require "active_record/railties/console_sandbox" if app.sandbox?
  require "active_record/base"
  console = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDERR)
  Rails.logger.extend ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast console
end
```

So one thing you could do when you first get into the console is to set `ActiveRecord::Base.logger` to a new logger that does not broadcast its messages to the console.  For example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new("log/development.log")
```

"log/development.log" can be changed to wherever you want to send the SQL output.